# Ways to diagonalize a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Matrix $\mathbf{D}$ is a full rank diagonal matrix. $\mathbf{ADA}^T=\mathbf{D}$.

Can we conclude that $\mathbf{A}^2=\mathbf{I}_n$? (edited from $\mathbf{A}=\pm\mathbf{I}$)

It's almost sure that some one has asked this question before, but I cannot find proper keywords to search for that post.

Comment: This question is going to win the prize for the worst title ever written. Moreover, what happens if the diagonal entries of $A$ equal $\pm 1$ but they are not the same number?

Comment: Are we talking about diagnoal or diagnoalizable matrices? They are not the same thing. Every diagnoal matrix is trivially diagnoalizable but not vice-versa. Also, I think you meant $A^{-1}$ instead of $A^T$

Comment: Did you mean $ADA^{-1}$ instead of $ADA^{T}$, as dREaM suggested?

Comment: I mean transpose.

Comment: And should in your first sentence one read "For any diagonal matrix $\mathbf D$," instead of "Matrix $\mathbf D$ is a diagonal matrix."?

Comment: @OskarLimka I'm not sure. Probability not, since $\mathbf{D}$ is an unknown but fixed matrix.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\\
D = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Often looking at the $2 \times 2$ case for problems like this will help you get a good idea of what's going on in general.

NB: I'm assuming that this wasn't a HW problem, because I'd hate to think that somewhere out there is a prof who writes things this badly.

NB 2: This answer the question whether you meant $A^t$ or $A^{-1}$, as they are the same in this case.

Comment: The OP has been edited. Can we conclude that $\mathbf{A}^2=\mathbf{I}$?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this answer addresses your question, but if we consider the matrices $A = D= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, then it holds:
$$A \cdot D \cdot A^T = D,$$ but $A^2 = A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$

Answer (score 2):

For the edited version, you can let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$;

then $ADA^{T}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=D$, but $A^2\ne I$.

---

For the case where D has full rank, we can let $A=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}\\\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$;

then $ADA^{T}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}=D$, but $A^2\ne I$.

Comment: What if the diagonal matrix is full rank? I edited it again.